# tick interval not set properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

.When i set the , tick amount, min and max,  the interval is not calculated properly in some cases for highcharts.Below is an example where its calculated properly. the interval is set at 0,1,2,3
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noel3090/ng0sj97q/1/)

```
       xAxis: [{
         min: 0,
         gridLineWidth: 1,
         endOnTick: true,
         tickAmount: 4,
         max:2.5
       }],
```

Where as in this fiddle  [fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/noel3090/v6xzua13/6/)

```
       xAxis: [{
          min: 0,
          gridLineWidth: 1,
          endOnTick: true,
          tickAmount: 3,
          max:14
       }],
```

the interval is set to 8.
Also its not taking the max value.
I want the interval set at 7 and not 8 and also max value to be 14 and not 16.

Comment: You can probably use `tickpositions` for your requirement.
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: Just like in the above comment - using tickPosition is a better solution to your case.